# JavaScript onclick dosen't work in front of other element which has onclick either

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code.

```
var child = window.open('', '', 'width=700, height=500'); 
child.moveTo(150, 150); 

if (child == null || typeof(child) == "undefined" || (child == null && child.outerWidth == 0) || 
    (child != null && child.outerHeight == 0) || child.test == "undefined" ){
    alert('please unlock your popup blocker.');
}else {
    child.document.write("<h2>Child Window</h2><div id='defaultOutput'></div><div id='firstDiv'></div><div id='secondDiv'></div>");
}

var seconddiv = child.document.querySelector('#secondDiv');

seconddiv.innerHTML += "<h1 id='clickable'>Click</h1>";

var onclickevent1 = function(e){  
    var event = e || window.Event;   
    window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google', 'width=600, height=400', true);
}

child.document.getElementById('clickable').onclick = onclickevent1;

seconddiv.innerHTML += "<h1 onclick=\"window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google2', 'width=600, height=400', true);\">Click2</h1>";
```

`onclickevent1` was working fine when it was alone, but when I added the line

```
seconddiv.innerHTML += "<h1 onclick=\"window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google2', 'width=600, height=400', true);\">Click2</h1>";
```

it is not working anymore.

what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to a container's `.innerHTML`, it re-parses the entire markup; any earlier references to elements higher in the script (such as elements with event handlers, and the event handlers themselves) get garbage collected and discarded.

Use `.appendChild` instead. (also, try to avoid inline JS; put your JS in your JS file, and put HTML in your HTML; separate presentation from content)

```
const h1 = seconddiv.appendChild(document.createElement('h1'));
h1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.open('http://www.google.com', 'google2', 'width=600, height=400', true)
});
h1.textContent = 'Click2';
```